# How can I output a single line of user input into multiple lines?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So basically, I'm trying to read a user input of a single line, but then split it up by space when I return the input. For example:

User input: 35 56 78 N

Desired output:

35

56

78

N

So far, I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GeographicCoordinatesExtractor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello and welcome to my program");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter geographical coordinates: ");
        String data = sc.next();
        sc.useDelimiter(" ");
        String value = data.split(" ")[0];

        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String sec = sc.next();

            System.out.println(value + "\n" + sec );
        }

    }}
```

And im getting:
35

56

35

78

instead of:

35

56

78

N

Answer (score 2):

As you want a single line as input, why are you using `Scanner#next`?
Just go for `Scanner#nextLine`, then split the result, and loop the resulting `String` array.

```
final String data = sc.nextLine();                  // 35 56 78 N
final String[] values = data.trim().split(" ");     // [35, 56, 78, N]

for (final String v : values) {
    System.out.println(v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are no " "'s (spaces) between for the last element. If you have 35 56 78 N, then the first three are registered as there are spaces after them, but there is no space after the N. I would suggest using substrings.